# Proof of voltage in lossless line

Tags: transmission-line, microwave

I'm currently a newbie in electronics engineering, and I want to prove the formula for a lossless Transmission lines, but I'm struggling with it.

Assuming we know the formulas for

U(z) = Ud0(exp(-γ*z)+ ΓL*exp(γ*z)

I(z) = Ud0/Z_c(exp(-γ*z)- ΓL*exp(γ*z)

where ΓL = Ui0/Ud0 = (ZL - ZC)/(Zc+ZL)

[image]

[image]

[image]

And now I want to prove

That U(z) = UL(cosβz) - jZc/ZL*sin(βz)

Where
γ = α + jβ and α = 0

I know it should be simple but I've been struggling for the past couple of hours and I really do want to understand it.

Keep in mind that R = C = 0.

Could you show me a nice, simple proof, to help me really understand this formula? I understand it best when I see a maths proof.

Thanks alot!
[image]

[image]

Comment: If the line is lossless, then R=G=0. You can then simplify.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Thank. I knew that. Forgot to add it to the question. I'm still not moving forward unfortunately...

Comment: When a transmission line is lossless, it's governing equation is the wave equation. Are you familiar with differential equations?

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with those, but as far as I can see, it can't be so difficult.  Could you maybe sketch a proof?

Comment: Your starting equations are the general solution of the common Telegrapher's Equation. (differential equation by Oliver Heaviside 150 years ago). Your circuit is the transmission line model which is used to derive Telegrapher's Equation. The general solution is found by applying differential equation solving methods to Telegrapher's Equation , the circuit doesn't give it directly. See ANY  textbook of transmission line theory for university level communication engineering students.